# How to make my post not public for a while?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, yaml-front-matter

I'm using `jekyll` and `github pages`. I'm currently busy with new post and it's not finished yet. I'm working from different places, that's why I need to `push` my changes to `github`. I created new post and push it on `github`. But after `push` my half-finished post is visible for everyone. I don't want to make it visible untill I finish it.

How I can hide it? Is there any standard way or flag?

I understand that I can copy it to another folder but it's not preffered way.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can include a line in your [YAML Front Matter](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/YAML-Front-Matter) to indicate whether a post is published or not:

```
published: true
```

or

```
published: false
```

Set `published` to `false` if you don’t want a post to show up when the site is generated.

Comment: is there something similar for pages?

Answer (score 5):

Those pages are visible only if you push them on [the `gh-pages` branch](https://github.com/blog/272-github-pages).

You could maintain a `gh-pages-draft` branch for you to push work in progress, and merge that branch to `gh-pages` when you are ready for publication.

For instance, the app [middleman-deploy](https://github.com/tvaughan/middleman-deploy) (for [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/), a static site generator) recently supports [pushing to other branches than just gh-pages](https://github.com/tvaughan/middleman-deploy/pull/4).

---

Note: [kleinfreund](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2036825/kleinfreund) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14428029/how-to-make-my-post-not-public-for-a-while/14433771?noredirect=1#comment38780316_14433771)

> The idea of drafts is backed into Jekyll.
>   Store post drafts in `/_drafts` and omit the date in the filename

This is detailed in "[Working with drafts](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/drafts/)"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but better solution in this case to use `published` flag.

Comment: The idea of drafts is backed into Jekyll. Store post drafts in `/_drafts` and omit the date in the filename: `post-title.md`

Comment: @kleinfreund good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, and added the link to the Jenkyll documentation.